# Filtering Results Based on Characters

Tags: javascript

I am wanting to return an array of values based on a certain combination of letters being included in each of the results. So, for instance, if I get an array of values of which some (but not all) contain the characters of "male" in the string, then I want to filter to return just those results. What would be the best way to accomplish this? Something like query.substring (as below) returns an altered value based on the numeric positioning of the characters, but what about a series of characters I'm searching for? Perhaps it's obvious but it's evading me at this point. Any help would be appreciated.

```
if (this.category === 'male') {
   this.query = this.query.substr(0, 2);
}
```

Comment: have a look at array's `filter()` function

Comment: Something like this you mean?
`let filterMale = query.filter((query) => {
  return query.includes('male');
})`